# JMS ConnectionConsumer usage example

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

Does anyone have an example of using JMS ConnectionConsumer (https://jms-spec.java.net/2.1-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/javax/jms/ConnectionConsumer.html) ?

I'm asking this question because I've found this page in google cache: 
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:M9C5d4PIZ-sJ:www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/nl/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032280_.htm+&cd=1&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru

It declares requeueing poison messages without any UOW if using ConnectionConsumer instead of MessageConsumer, and I need exactly that behaviour.

I need that for EJB application (Websphere AS), but it would be helpful to know just any working usecase (standalone client or whatever). 
Yet I can't find any clue about how ConnectionConsumer could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Within a MDB scenario the MQ resource adapter we'll be using a connection consumer. This offs the JMS api that is being used.

So if you are using an MDB the messages that trigger the MDB well be subject to the poison message handing add described.

That page is in the current knowledge centre.

Comment: Not sure I got the point, sorry. Do you mean that ConnectionConsumer could be used in J2EE container? The spec declares that methods like "createConnectionConsumer" must mot be called from J2EE app. https://jms-spec.java.net/2.1-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/javax/jms/Connection.html#createConnectionConsumer%28javax.jms.Destination,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.jms.ServerSessionPool,%20int%29